# deleting a file from RTC in command line

Tags: rtc

in my sandbox, there is a new file, a file changed and a file deleted.

if i run "lscm checkin ." from the root this is taken care.
But i was wondering, if i want to handle it one by one, ie run lscm status - collect all changes - run checkin on them one by one, how do i handle the deleted files. An lscm checkin on the deleted file would return an error saying the file is not present.
I want to do it this way, as my project is very deep and has around 11K files and around 2K directories, and so hope to gain some performance by running checkin only for the changed files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ["Using Rational Team Concert" article](https://jazz.net/library/article/979/) does mention:

> When items are deleted there is a special way to check in the delete.
>   **You invoke the checkin command in the normal way but you provide the path to the parent directory of the deleted item instead of the path to the item itself**.

So there doesn't seem to be a finer-grained checkin for deleted resources.

Comment: hmm , interesting. should check this. Thanks.